# Cannot build Android Version of my App due to react-native-orientation

Tags: android, react-native, orientation

I used the `react-native-orientation` package in my project, and linked it using `npx pod-install`. This worked on iOS and now my app is fully released on the App Store. Then when I tried to create an Android build, I kept getting the following error from Android Studio:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-orientation'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I followed then, the manual instructions for linking `react-native-orientation` to the Android directory and it did nothing. I understand that `pod-install` is just for iOS, but `react-native link` is deprecated now, is it not? I can't even run it, as it just tells me that `link` is an unrecognized command. So if the manual linking won't work, and the auto-linking doesn't exist evidently, what course of action do I have?

Comment: You sure that `compile project(':react-native-orientation')` was added to `android/app/build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is

Comment: Than try change it to `implementation project(':react-native-orientation')`. Compile method is deprecated

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

The problem is that on gradlew 7, 'compile' keyword is deprecated in favor of 'implementation'.

And the proper way is not changing inside /node_modules/ folder, but making a patch.
In my case I had to manually modify the automated patch made by patch-package.

This issue helped me: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation/issues/407

The patch is as bellow (do not copy the first 2 lines, let patch-package create those):

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-orientation/android/src/main/java/com/github/yamill/orientation/OrientationModule.java b/node_modules/react-native-orientation/android/src/main/java/com/github/yamill/orientation/OrientationModule.java
index 85331ae..787f60f 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-orientation/android/build.gradle
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-orientation/android/build.gradle
@@ -16,5 +16,5 @@ android {
 }

 dependencies {
-    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
+    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
 }
```